# How to make a column bold in HTML output

Tags: html, css, powershell

Below is my PowerShell script. It produces a nicely formatted HTML table. I'd like to make a single column bold (Full % column). I can't for the life of me think of a way to do it.

I've tried inserting bold tags in different places and tried thinking of a way to use replace but since the numbers change in the columns I can't think of a way to do it.

```
$symmid = 1555
$command1 = symfast -sid $symmid list -association -demand
$command2 = symcfg -sid $symmid list -thin -pool -detail -gb
$basedir = "C:\ts\Scripts"
$timestamp = Get-Date -Format ddMMyyyy
$CSSFile = "$basedir\csstemplate.css"

$css = get-content $CSSFile


$command1 > $basedir\archive_vp\archive_$timestamp.txt
$command2 > $basedir\archive_pool\archive_$timestamp.txt

$regex = '(?ms)P O O L S(.+?)\r\n\s*\r\n'
$command2 = $command2 -join "`r`n"
$command2 = [regex]::Matches($command2,$regex) | foreach {$_.groups[1].value}
$command2 = $command2 -split "`r`n" | select -Skip 5

$command2Format = $command2 | % {
  $column = $_ -split ' +'
  $hash = [ordered]@{
   'Pool Name'  = $column[0]
   'Flags PTECSL'  = $column[1]
   'Dev Config'    = $column[2]
   'Total GBs'      = $column[3]
   'Usable GBs'    = $column[4]
   'Free GBs'       = $column[5]
   'Used GBs'       = $column[6]
   'Full (%)'       = $column[7]
   'Subs (%)'       = $column[8]
   'Comp (%)'       = $column[9]
   'Shared GBs'    = $column[10]


 }
 New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property $hash
} | ConvertTo-Html -Head $a


function get-css
{
    foreach($line in $css)
    {
        $style += $line
    }
    return $style
}


$style = "<style>"
$style = get-css
$style += "</style>"

$report = "<html><head>$style</head><body>$command2Format</body></html>"


$report | Out-File $basedir\test.html
Invoke-Expression $basedir\test.html
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to follow this basic example to get what you are looking for

```
$a = @"
<style>
    TD:nth-child(1){font-weight: bold}
</style>
"@

Get-ChildItem c:\temp -Directory | Select Name,lastwritetime | ConvertTo-Html -Head $a | Set-Content c:\temp\file.html 
ii c:\temp\file.html
```

So as defined by `nth-child(1)` the first column of data will have its text **bolded**. You should be able to accomplish the same thing with the 7th column.

Yes, like [Tim Ferrill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29398383/3829407) says, you would need browser support for this but that should not be a tall order.

[image: Sample Output]

Answer (score 2):

Can you count on CSS3? If so you can use the `:nth-Child()` selector. Details here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp